# How to import sql.gz file to mysql database using python script?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7, mysql, mysql-python

I export a database using `mysqldump` in the `sql.gz` format using a python script. How can I import that `sql.gz` file using this python script?

I wrote code which works for `.sql` or `.txt` files.

```
import MySQLdb


filename = self.ui.txtFileLocationImport.text()

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(dbHostName, dbUser, dbPassword, databaseName)

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

#Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
f = open(filename , 'r')
try:
    cursor.execute('SET foreign_key_checks = 0')
    for sql in f:
        if sql == '\n' or sql[0] == '/':
            pass
        else:
            # Execute the SQL command
            cursor.execute(str(sql))

    #Commit your changes in the database
    cursor.execute('SET foreign_key_checks = 1')
    db.commit()
except Exception as e:
   print e
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

#close file
f.close()
# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

This only works for `.txt` and `.sql` file. How can I make this read a `sql.gz` file?

Answer (score 1):

With the contents of the [`gzip`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) module.